# tf.initialize_variables() inconvenience - FailedPreconditionError tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I want to be able to initialize tensorflow variables with a specific list using `tf.initialize_variables()`. So, to test the case I am trying this but it fails:

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables(tf.all_variables()))
```

with the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Layer_0/Initialize_Variables/weights
```

What is really weird to me, is that it works this way:

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([tf.all_variables()[0]]))
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([tf.all_variables()[1]]))
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([tf.all_variables()[2]]))
...
```

So, the same happens if I create my own list of variables that I want to initialize. Probably I am misunderstanding something of the tensorflow mechanisms. Any ideas? I'd be glad if I don't have to do that using a loop for each variable.

Comment: That seems weird/unexpected, do you have a self-contained example which shows this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code, but my guess is that you're initializing one variable from another variable, which is a little tricky in TensorFlow. For example, I imagine you're doing something like this:

```
v_1 = tf.Variable(...)
v_2 = tf.Variable(v_1)
```

This will fail if you try to do `sess.run(tf.initalize_all_variables())` because it will attempt to initialize `v_1` and `v_2` in parallel, but the initialization of `v_2` will fail (because its input is currently uninitialized).

If you iterate over the `tf.all_variables()` list in increasing order, it will work, because `v_1` is added to the list before `v_2`, so running things sequentially will cause `v_1` to be initialized before `v_2`. (At a guess, if you iterated over `tf.all_variables()` in *reverse* order, it would fail with a similar error.)

The fix is a bit subtle: any time you initialize a variable `v_2` from another variable `v_1`, you should use [`v_1.initialized_value()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.initialized_value) as the argument to `v_2`'s constructor:

```
v_1 = tf.Variable(...)
v_2 = tf.Variable(v_1.initialized_value())
```

Using `v_1.initialized_value` adds a control dependency between the two initializers, so that `v_1` is initialized before `v_2`, even if you try to initialize them in parallel.

Comment: Very good guess. I was about to post a self contained example but you came first. In fact I am using the tf.identity() of another value to initialize a new one, and I didn't suspected the dependency issue (even if I went through the "sort of unclear" explanation of Variable.initialized_value() on the documentation a couple of times). Thanks!